# Create a new collection from child attributes in nestled array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a structure similar to this (only test data, so typos are irrelevant):

```
 "People" :  [
      {
        "name": "Bob",
        "animals" : [{
          "name" : "Scott",
          "type" : "Cat"
        },
        {
          "name" : "Eva",
          "type" : "Cat"
        }
        {
          "name" : "Sven",
          "type" : "Dog"
        }]
      },
      {
        "name": "Bob",
        "animals" : [{
          "name" : "Chris",
          "type" : "Dog"
        },
        {
          "name" : "Greg",
          "type" : "Cat"
        },
        {
          "name" : "Ior",
          "type" : "Horse"
        }]
      }
    ]
```

Basically what I want to do is to get all unique animal types from this collection. My problem is mapping into two arrays (`People : [], Animals : []`). The question:

How do I .map all the "type" attributes to get a new unique collection? like:

```
["Cat", "Dog", "Horse"]
```

Will update if I get an example done using C# LINQ.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Hint : `reduce`, `map`, `concat` and finally to `Set` to `Array`.

Comment: @gurvinder372 will look into reduce and concat and see if it's of use here... Familiar with Set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let _animals = {}
People.forEach(person => {
  person.animals.forEach(animal => {
     _animals[animal.name] = true 
  })
})
let result = Object.keys(_animals)
```

Enhanced with more es6:

```
let _animals = {}
People.forEach(({animals}) =>
    animals.forEach(({name}) =>
    _animals[name] = true 
  )
)
let result = Object.keys(animals)
```

Comment: This was a great way of doing it. Will have to look into use cases for `.forEach` in javascript as I've kind of settled with `.filter`, `.map` and `.find`. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for more info on `animalsFrom()`.

See [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Flattening Arrays`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865042/5566355) for more info on the latter method (`listAnimals()`).

```js
// Input.
const input = {"people":  [{"name": "Bob","animals": [{"name": "Scott","type": "Cat"},{"name" : "Eva","type": "Cat"},{"name" : "Sven","type": "Dog"}]},{"name": "Bob","animals": [{"name" : "Chris","type" : "Dog"},{"name": "Greg","type": "Cat"},{"name": "Ior","type": "Horse"}]}]}

// Animals From.
const animalsFrom = ({people}) => {
  
  const animals = new Set()
  
  people.forEach(person => {
    person.animals.forEach(animal => animals.add(animal.type))
  }) 

  return [...animals.values()]
}

// List Animals (Advanced).
const listAnimals = ({people}) => [...new Set([].concat.apply([], people.map(({animals}) => animals.map(({type}) => type))))]

// Proof.
console.log('Animals From', animalsFrom(input))
console.log('List Animals', listAnimals(input))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var unique = {};   // Create an associative array 
for (j = 0; j < People.length; j++) { // Iterate through Parents
    for(i = 0; i < People[j].animals.length; i++) { // Iterate through animals
        var node = unique[People[j].animals[i].type] = unique[People[j].animals[i].type] || {}; 
        // Here unique is built. If there is no entry with the current type as the id, a new entry in unique will be added. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## ES6

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`new Set([])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and the [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const arr = [{
    "name": "Bob",
    "animals": [{
        "name": "Scott",
        "type": "Cat"
    }, {
        "name": "Eva",
        "type": "Cat"
    }, {
        "name": "Sven",
        "type": "Dog"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Bob",
    "animals": [{
        "name": "Chris",
        "type": "Dog"
    }, {
        "name": "Greg",
        "type": "Cat"
    }, {
        "name": "Ior",
        "type": "Horse"
    }]
}];

let result = arr.reduce((r, {animals}) =>[...r,...animals.map(({type})=>type)], []);


console.log([ ...new Set(result)]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce`, `map`, `concat` and finally to `Set` to `Array` as shown below

```
var output = [...new Set( arr.reduce( (a,c) => a.concat( c.animals.map( s => s.type )) , []))]
```

**Explanation**

- Use `reduce` to iterate array (`people`) to get all values for animals type
- Use `map` to iterate animals and return their types, and concatenate result of `map` to accumulator `a`
- Use `Set` to remove duplicates.
- Use spread operator `...` to convert back to `Array`.

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
    "name": "Bob",
    "animals": [{
        "name": "Scott",
        "type": "Cat"
      },
      {
        "name": "Eva",
        "type": "Cat"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sven",
        "type": "Dog"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "animals": [{
        "name": "Chris",
        "type": "Dog"
      },
      {
        "name": "Greg",
        "type": "Cat"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ior",
        "type": "Horse"
      }
    ]
  }
];
var output = [...new Set(arr.reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c.animals.map(s => s.type)), []))];
console.log(output);
```